# Check if variables are empty

Tags: php, if-statement

I have `$var1`, `$var2`, `$var3` and `$type`. I want to check if `$var1` and `$var2` are empty when `$type=1` but when `$type=2` I want to check if `$var1`, `$var2` and `$var3` are empty.

I've tried with

```
 if(($type==1 AND empty($var) AND empty($var1)) OR ($type==2 AND empty($var1) AND empty($var2) AND empty($var3)))
 {//...}
```

but it doesn't work in the second case when `$type=2;`
So how to get this done with one if statement?

Comment: Looks valid to me. Ugly, but valid.

Comment: You are using `$var` in your first empty statement and `$var1` when checking type2. Intended or typo?

Comment: Turns out "doesn't work" -- meaningless as it is -- isn't even accurate. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use "if", but take advantage of dropping through the cases in a switch

```
$result = TRUE;
switch ($type) {
    case 2:
        $result = $result && empty($var3);
    case 1:
        $result = $result && empty($var2);
        $result = $result && empty($var1);
        break;
    default:
        $result = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I like that approach. In case 1 you could write `$result = $result && empty($var2) && empty($var1);`

Comment: So I can't do it with just one if but with multiple if statements + switch?

Comment: @lam3r4370: Yes, you can. Your code works just fine the way it is (except that it is ugly, so it's _recommended_ to change it). See my answer. In fact, read _all_ the answers, not just the top one.

Comment: @knittl - I would have done that if I'd been doing it for myself, but wrote it longhand for the benefit of the OP. Allowing dropthrough rather than using break in a case can sometimes be useful, as in this case.... but in the real world I'd also put a comment in explaining why no break, else some other developer might consider it an error

Comment: Whilst good advice, this doesn't answer the stated question. The question is "why doesn't my code perform the function I expect of it?" The answer is "it does".

Comment: OK, my code really works but I think that Your solution is better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use multiple if statements:

```
switch($type) {
  case 1: if(empty($var1) && empty($var2)) {
    …
  }
  break;
  case 2: if(empty($var1) && empty($var2) && empty($var3)) {
    …
  }
   break;
}
```

Comment: Whilst good advice, this doesn't answer the stated question. The question is "why doesn't my code perform the function I expect of it?" The answer is "it does".

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you wrote `$var` instead of `$var1`.

See, with line breaks:

```
if (
    ($type==1 AND empty($var) AND empty($var1))
   OR
    ($type==2 AND empty($var1) AND empty($var2) AND empty($var3))
   ) {}
//                        ^
```

You'd have spotted this if your code weren't completely illegible.

Otherwise, [your code *does* perform as advertised](http://ideone.com/yeUcq):

```
<?php
$type = 2;
$var  = '';
$var1 = '';
$var2 = '';
$var3 = '';

if(($type==1 AND empty($var) AND empty($var1)) OR ($type==2 AND empty($var1) AND empty($var2) AND empty($var3))) {
   echo '!';
}

// Output: !
?>
```

That fact makes this a total non-question. Please take greater care over your questions in future, providing actual testcases that *actually* reproduce the problem, to prove that you haven't just made some other mistake that you're not showing us.

Comment: You are right.I didn't know this site thus I didn't reproduce the problem.Thanks for the advices :)